# What is a good way to toggle configuration file settings?

Tags: python, bash, configuration

I'd like to modify some config settings via the command line, e.g. `sshd_config`'s `UsePAM`. The "problem" is that depending on the system, the existing config file either has only the one entry with the setting `yes` or `no`, or it has both lines but one of them commented out, or the setting does not yet exist, relying on a default value. Sure enough I can simply

```
sed -i '/^.*UsePAM/d;' /etc/sshd_config  # remove all occurrences so far
echo "UsePAM yes" >> /etc/sshd_config    # append the new value to the end
```

(as long as no sections are involved), but that's rather suboptimal. I could write a small Python program to manually implement the algorithm

```
if setting not present:
    append it to the correct section
elif setting present both commented and not:
    swap commenting if necessary
else:
    set/uncomment the single occurrence of the setting
```

but are there simpler means for this?

Comment: a half-step up would be to use [`augtool`](http://augeas.net/tour.html) instead of `sed/echo`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, I'll have a look at that!